# How to stop resize when meet the width size of an element

Tags: jquery

I wanted this #map element resize whenever the window resize. However, if the browser window resize back and meet the 930 pixel width, the #map element should stop resizing even if the browser extend to full screen width.

Here's my actual code.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  var _frameY = $(window).height(),
      _frameX = $(window).width(),
      _map    = $('#map');

  if (_frameX <= _map.width()) {
    _map.css({ 'width': _frameX, 'height': _frameY });
  } else if (_frameX >= 930) {
    _map.css({ 'width': _frameX, 'height': _frameY });
  }

}).resize();
```

I wanted to maintain the resizing function below 930 pixel of the #map, but when the browser screen-width resize and over it to 931 pixel, the #map element should stop resizing and stay at 930 pixel width.

Comment: Can't you simply stop setting the css attribute in the else if case? I am confused what your exact problem is.

Comment: Actually the code was given... and i am trying to figure out what was causing of my #map still resizing when the main browser width was over 930 pixel width. So in that case, i overlooked the _map.width() instead of the value (930). I posted my answer to clear this issue. Sorry to confuse you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing my issue here. So instead of pulling out the value of the `_map.width()`, i use the exact value that my CSS throw on main frame.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  var _frameY = $(window).height(),
      _frameX = $(window).width(),
      _map    = $('#map');

  if (_frameX <= 930) {
    _map.css({ 'width': _frameX, 'height': _frameY });
  } else if (_frameX >= 930) {
    _map.css({ 'width': 930, 'height': 590 });
  }

}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong because ".width()" return the current width of the element and not the value in the CSS element. so you have to set in your code the 930px value in your condition.

```
  if (_frameX <= _map.width()) {
    _map.css({ 'width': _frameX, 'height': _frameY });
  } else if (_frameX >= 930) {
    _map.css({ 'width': _frameX, 'height': _frameY });
  }
```

Comment: Alright, i see my mistake here... I overlooked the current frame of ".mapWrapper" over the #map where the SVG was placed. Thanks for clearing out the ".width()" portion.